# Proving surjectivity of the $J$-invariant

Tags: complex-analysis, elliptic-curves, modular-forms, elliptic-functions

I'm trying to understand the following Theorem and proof in Apostol's *Modular Functions and Dirichlet Series in Number Theory*. The $J$-invariant is defined by

$ J(\tau)=\frac{g_2(1,\tau)}{g_2(1,\tau)^3-27g_3(1,\tau)^2}$

($g_{2k}$ being the Eisenstein series) and the fundamental region $R_{\Gamma}$ is

$R_{\Gamma}=\{\tau\in H:|\tau|>1,|\tau+\bar{\tau}|<1\}$ with $\rho=e^{\pi i/3}.$

> **Theorem**: The function $J$ takes on every value exactly once in the closure of $R_{\Gamma}$. In particular, at the vertices we have $J(\rho)=0,J(i)=1,J(i\infty)=\infty$. There is a first order pole at $i\infty$, a triple zero at $\rho$, and $J(\tau)-1$ has a double zero at $\tau=i$
>
> **Proof**:First we verify that $g_2(\rho)=0$ and $g_3(i)=0$. Since $\rho^3=1$ and $\rho^2+\rho+1=0$ we have
>
> $\frac{1}{60}g_2(\rho)=\sum \frac{1}{(m+n\rho)^4}=\frac{1}{\rho}\sum \frac{1}{(n-m-m\rho)^4}=\frac{1}{\rho}\sum \frac{1}{(N+M\rho)^4}=\frac{1}{60\rho}g_2(\rho),$
>
> so $g_2(\rho)=0$. A similar argument shows $g_3(i)=0$. Therefore
>
> $J(\rho)=\frac{g_2(\rho)^3}{\Delta(\rho)}=0,J(i)=\frac{g_2(i)^3}{g_2(i)^3}=2.$
>
> The multiplicities follow from the above Theorem.

(slightly edited for legibility; the Theorem referenced at the end is just the result that counting multiplicity $J$ has the same number of zeros and poles)

My problem is that I have no idea how what is shown in the proof implies surjectivity. I understand that if the fundamental region was a compact Riemann surface then this would follow since $J(i\infty)=\infty$ would imply the co-domain is the Riemann sphere; but I don't understand how $R_{\Gamma}$ is such, perhaps I'm missing something?

I'm writing an undergraduate thesis that only requires this function to be surjective. So, I'm trying to minimize the amount of machinery used.

Comment: The modular curve $\bigcup_{\Im(z)>0}SL_2(\Bbb{Z})z\bigcup SL_2(\Bbb{Z})i\infty$ is of course a compact Riemann surface. And $J-a$ is meromorphic on it with only one simple pole at $i\infty$. Thus $J-a$ has only one simple zero. That a meromorphic function has the same number of zeros/poles follows from $\int_{\partial U}f'/f = 0$ where $U$ is a fundamental domain with no zeros/poles of $f$ on the boundary, whose boundary is finitely many curves traversed in opposite directions. Since $J$ has some zeros/poles on the boundary it gets to Apostol's integral.

Comment: @reuns In Apostol's book he doesn't prove that the domain of $J$ is that set-theoretic union you gave, only that it's invariant under $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$. Is there somewhere perhaps you could point me to that shows how the upper half-plane can be quotiented to obtain that domain? I'm still new to Riemann surfaces..

Comment: I'm not sure of what you are asking. It is obvious that the upper half-plane quotiented by $SL_2(Z)$ (which acts discretely) is a Riemann surface. The complex topology is the one inherited from $\Bbb{H}$. The charts are the obvious ones, except at $i$ and $e^{2i\pi /3}$ because there are some $\gamma$ sending them to themselves. The chart at $i$ is $s\to SL_2(Z)ie^{s^{1/2}}$. Then we need to show that adding the chart $s\to \frac{\log s}{2i\pi}, 0\to SL_2(Z)i\infty$ makes it compact (ie. covered by the image of closed disks by finitely many charts)

Comment: Overall $f$ is meromorphic on the modular curve iff it is $SL_2(Z)$ invariant, meromorphic on $\Im(z) > 0$ and $f(\frac{\log s}{2i\pi})$ is meromorphic at $0$. The  underlying Riemann surface is uniquely defined by this. It is obvious that if $f$ is analytic on the modular curve then it attains its maximum modulus at some point thus it is constant, whence the underlying Riemann surface is automatically compact.